# Video uploading using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("demo",$con);

extract($_POST);

$target_dir = "test_upload/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if($upd)
{
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "mpeg")
{
    echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
} 

else
{

$video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

mysql_query("insert into video(video_name) values('$video_path')");

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);

echo "uploaded ";

}

}

//display all uploaded video

if($disp)

{

$query=mysql_query("select * from video");

    while($all_video=mysql_fetch_array($query))

    {
?>

     <video width="300" height="200" controls>
    <source src="test_upload/<?php echo $all_video['video_name']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video> 

    <?php } } ?>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table border="1">

<tr>

<Td>Upload  Video</td></tr>

<Tr><td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/></td></tr>

<tr><td>

<input type="submit" value="Uplaod Video" name="upd"/>

<input type="submit" value="Display Video" name="disp"/>

</td></tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Using this code I tried to **upload video**. **Video name** is properly saved in the **database** but problem is, that video **does not move** in the **particular folder**. So when I write the select query, that time video does not display.

Anyone, help me with the proper explanation.

I am new in programming language

Comment: can you inspect element on video tag and show me your video tag here ?

Comment: <source src="test_upload/kabaddi.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: see the src attribute do not contain full path of the video. Try to set full path of video file in src attribute.

Comment: pleas explain me proper i cant understood what i do if any small example;e code available then send me

Comment: for example..    <source src="localhost/test_upload/kabaddi.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Answer (score 0):

First move to the folder and if moved then insert into the database. Then, Check the maximum upload size of your server.

```
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        mysql_query("insert into video(video_name) values('$video_path')");
        echo "Uploaded successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

Change your php.ini file `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` whatever the size you want. Example i given 100M - 100MB

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 100M 

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: i use your  code that time error message come video not move

Comment: Did you changed the upload_max_filesize  size?